# Default VNC server not viewing correctly in VNC viewer

Tags: pi-3, remote, vnc

I am trying to access my pi remotely using VNC. However the automatic server that is created on startup, when no HDMI is attached, is not viewed correctly in VNC viewer. Only a very small portion of the screen is displayed and I am not able to scroll to other sections of the page. I have tried this on the desktop viewer and mobile viewer and the problem is the same.

If I create a server using ssh with vncserver :1, the resulting virtual window is correct and I am able to scroll to different parts of the screen. However this is no use to me as I would like to access the pi over the VNC cloud so rely on the vncserver that is created at startup.

Is there a way of changing the code when the raspberry pi starts up that creates a default window that can be scrolled in VNC viewer?

Comment: I can promise you that you will be much happier using xrdp.  `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install xrdp`  - then use Windows Remote Desktop or `remmina` for RDP access.  Also, on Linux `remmina` is the best VNC client, and `tightvnc client` is best on Windows for VNC access.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I solved this problem by adjusting the display options in Raspi-config. [Using the following](https://support.realvnc.com/knowledgebase/article/View/523/2/troubleshooting-vnc-server-on-the-raspberry-pi):

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Advanced Options > Resolution > DMT Mode 85 1280x720

Comment: Then in the terminal you type `vncserver` and set a password for access.

Answer (score 3):

There are two important steps one can take to make life easier.

1. To start vncserver on startup:

> Add: -su - -c '/user/bin/vncserver :1' to
>   "/etc/rc.local" file.

2. Change the screen size on your Pi to load properly according to your client machine resolution.

> Type in terminal: sudo raspi-config

Go to advanced option > resolution > [select resolution accordingly]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have that working you might want to consider using Remote Desktop Protocol.

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

All Windows machines have an RDP client called Remote Desktop Connection.

Plus, you can use Remmina on linux machines as a client also.

```
sudo apt-get install remmina
```

Remmina has the advantage that it can connect via either VNC or RDP, and uses a tabbed interface if you connect to more than one server.